# Check Treeview nodes depending MySQL table C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, treeview, treenode

Table A [Modules]:

```
module_id     module_name
==========================
1             Articles
2             Suppliers
3             Cash
```

Table B [ModulesOptions]:

```
moduleoption_id     module_id     moduleoption_name
====================================================
1                   1             New Article
2                   1             Edit Article
3                   2             New Supplier
4                   2             Edit Supplier
5                   3             New Invoice
```

Table C [usersprivileges]

```
user_id       moduleoption_id
==========================
1             1
1             3
```

Populate TreeStateView code: (only create the parent and childNodes but not yet the mark)

```
    DataRelation DataRelation = DataSet.Relations.Add("Modules_to_Modules_Options", DataSet.Tables["Modules"].Columns["module_id"], DataSet.Tables["ModulesOptions"].Columns["module_id"]);
    foreach (DataRow DataRow in DataSet.Tables["Modules"].Rows)
    {
        TreeNode TreeNode = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode.Text = DataRow["module_name"].ToString();
        TreeNode.Tag = DataRow["module_id"].ToString();
        TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 0;
        TreeNode.Expand();

        foreach (DataRow DataRowChild in DataRow.GetChildRows("Modules_to_Modules_Options"))
        {
            TreeNode TreeNodeChild = new TreeNode();
            TreeNodeChild.Text = DataRowChild["moduleoption_name"].ToString();
            TreeNodeChild.Tag = DataRowChild["moduleoption_id"].ToString();
            TreeNode.Nodes.Add(TreeNodeChild);
        }
        this.UsersEdit_TreeView_ModulesOptions.Nodes.Add(TreeNode);
    }
```

The TreeView control have the property `Checkboxes = true`

Each parent nodes have 3 States:

```
TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 0; // No Checked
TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 1; // Checked
TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 2; // Mixed
```

I Need to mark each parent node (modules) depending table (usersprivileges)

```
If (user have all modulesoptions privileges)
{
 TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 1; // Checked
} elseif (user have some modulesoptions checked)
{
 TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 2; // Mixed
} else {
TreeNode.StateImageIndex = 0; // No Checked
}
```

According to the user (user_id: 1)

```
+---Articles (Mixed)
|   |
|   +--------New Article <-- (Checked)
|   +--------Edit Article <-- (NO Checked)
|
+---Suppliers (NO Checked)
|   |
|   +--------New Supplier <-- (NO Checked)
|   +--------Edit Supplier <--(NO Checked)
|
+---Cash (Checked)
|   |
|   +--------New Invoice <-- (Checked)
|
```

[image]

Comment: Might there be a question or a description of the problem added to all this in the near future?  You'll have a lot more luck attracting a member to answer.

Comment: Sorry, but please take a look to my updated question, thank you.

Comment: as a general rule, if there is no question mark, it is not a question.